# Group messaging system , MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, chat

-

Hello , i have next database structure for chat groups

> Table `chat_rooms`
>   `( id , title , user_id )`
>
> Table `room_users`
>   `( id , user_id , room_id , online )`
>
> Table `room_messages`
>   `( id , user_id , room_id , message , created_at )`
>
> Table `users`
>   `( id , email , firstname , lastname , company_id )`
>
> `online` indicates when user was last time **online** in this room

So , i need to get all users list as a contact list , but with them i need to get unread messages.

For e.g. I'm user with id = `1` and company_id = `3`
I want to get all users within company_id = `3` and if i have a common room with user **N** , let's take id = `3` , if we don't room_id should be `0`

Where of course , we are alone , him and i , i know that i need to use **having** , but don't understand where i should.

Furthermore i need to get count of messages and last message which user id = `3` sent when user id = `1` wasn't `online` , `room_messages.created_at > room_users.online` , and i need user `id , email , firstname , lastname`.

So , at final i should get something like that:

`room_id , user_id , unread , email , firstname , lastname , last_message`

What have i done so far..

```
SELECT users.id                      AS user_id, 
   Ifnull(room_users.room_id, 0) AS room_id, 
   users.firstname               AS firstname, 
   users.lastname                AS lastname, 
   users.email                   AS email, 
   Ifnull(k.unread, 0)           AS unread 

FROM   users 
   LEFT JOIN room_users 
          ON users.id = room_users.user_id 
             AND room_users.user_id != 3 
   LEFT JOIN (SELECT l.room_id, 
                     l.user_id, 
                     Count(m.id) AS unread 
              FROM   room_users AS l 
                     LEFT JOIN room_messages m 
                            ON m.room_id = l.room_id 
                               AND ( l.online IS NULL 
                                      OR m.created_at > l.online ) 
                               AND m.user_id != 3 
              WHERE  l.user_id = 3 
              GROUP  BY l.room_id) AS k 
          ON room_users.room_id = k.room_id 
WHERE  users.company_id = 3 
   AND users.id != 3
```

Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d4a35/2

Comment: Can you add some sample data and expected output? I'm confused as to what you are trying to do. Sentence: `i need to extract all users list as contacts , but i need to get count of unread messages.` doesn't make sense. Please revise.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query